# Difference between 'web' and 'auth' middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, middleware

I have faced some problem when i am going to use `middleware` group of **Laravel 5.2** framework.

My **routes.php** file is:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories'], function () {
    Route::get('all', ['as' => 'allCategory' , 'uses' => 'CategoryController@index']);
    Route::get('add', ['as' => 'addCategory', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@create']);
    Route::get('edit/{id}', ['as' => 'editCategory', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@edit']);
    Route::post('save', ['as' => 'saveCategory', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@store']);
    Route::put('update', ['as' => 'updateCategory', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@update']);
    Route::get('delete/{id}', ['as' => 'deleteCategory', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@destroy']);

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

});
```

I am using here laravel defaults **login/registration** authentication.Using `php artisan make:auth` command.I want to give user restricted for some `routes` such as `categories` route group.So,

1. How can i restrict a user for categories route group?
2. If i use **Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {   });** then i got an error. So what is the difference between `'web'`
   and `'auth'` `middleware` ?

Thanks.

**N.B : If you need to know about any files then just comment me below i will add those files.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature of laravel 5.2. 2 default middleware is web and api.

You need place category group route inside **web** middleware.

Web middleware make your request contains cookies, session, csrf_token used for authentication. Otherwise, **api** middleware used for application that simple query get or post without request header, assume mobile app.

Auth middleware **based on** web middleware.

Comment: add ***'middleware' => 'auth'*** into categories route group. Dont forget place it inside web middleware, after Route::auth();

Comment: I am beginner in laravel.Could you tell me how to add `middleware' => 'auth'` into categories group? What will be categories route after this?

Comment: ***Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () { .. }***